# How can I get 'date' command show AM/PM time by default

Tags: date

I am looking to have my `date` command show time:

```
mohi@DESKTOP-PM4LGGS:~/Dropbox/mpl$ date
Mon, Jul 30, 2018  3:31:41 PM
```

like I am seeing in my `Git Bash` on my office Windows. How can I get my `date` command show AM/PM time by default on my home `Ubuntu 18.04 LTS (GNOME Terminal)`?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Supplying `date` with an explicit format string would do this:

```
$ date +'%a, %b %d, %Y  %r'
Mon, Jul 30, 2018  11:45:58 AM
```

or

```
$ date +'%a, %b %d, %Y %l:%M:%S %p'
```

where `%l:%M:%S %p` is a bit more locale-independent than `%r` might be.

As a shell function that overloads `date` with this format only when called without any options:

```
date () {
    [ "$#" -eq 0 ] && set -- +'%a, %b %d, %Y  %r'
    command date "$@"
}
```

You would execute the function definition as written above directly in your interactive shell to make it available there, or put it wherever you ordinarily put aliases.

Comment: Note that the expansion of `%r` is locale-dependent and is not guaranteed to contain AM/PM. For instance here on a GNU system, I get `11:56:02 am BST` in a British locale and `11:56:02` in a French locale. in the C/POSIX locale, you'd get `01:23:44 PM` instead of `1:23:44 PM`.

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
localectl set-locale LC_TIME=en_US.UTF-8
```

Comment: That has the disadvantage that it puts day and month wrong way around (though the example in the question suggests that's probably acceptable).

Answer (score -3):

You can add your preferred command as an alias to the `~/.bash_aliases` or `~/.bashrc` file.

```
alias d='date +"%a, %h %d, %Y %r"'
```

For the change to take effect, you have to run:

```
source ~/.bash_aliases
```

Then, you can use `d` to get the date in your desired format.